# How to automate Gmail Login to use HttpsURLConnection and Jsoup in Java 8

Tags: java, https, jsoup

I am looking into how to automate the login to an https site that has a form that I need to invoke later on. I came across the example below which explains how to login to gmail; However, the issue that I an having is regardless of the credential used, I always get 200Ok. can someone help troubleshooting this issue for me?

```
public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
    String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox";

    HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username@gmail.com", "password");



    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(url, postParams);



    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for


    // 3. success then go to gmail.
    String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("Email"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("Passwd"))
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(paramList.toString());
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without saying it's impossible, you'll have a LOT of hard and tedious work to succeed on this path. The Gmail login is a model of complication. It is not a mere form parameters sending...

Hopefully, there is a really highspeed path: [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).
You'll find the handy [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) in order to automate the Gmail login.
Here is a summary:

#### Prerequesites

- Java 1.7 or greater.
- Gradle 2.3 or greater.
- Access to the internet and a web browser.
- A Google account with Gmail enabled.

#### Step 1: Turn on the Gmail API

Simple step by step instructions to prepare and setup your Gmail API use.

#### Step 2: Prepare the project

Prepare the project dependencies with Gradle. You may setup the dependencies either manually or with another builder (Maven etc).

#### Step 3: Set up the sample

You can copy or download a full working sample code to login into Gmail.

#### See also:

---

---

In this example, we will log into the [GitHub](https://github.com/) website by using the [FormElement](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html) class.

```
// # Constants used in this example
final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"; 
final String LOGIN_FORM_URL = "https://github.com/login";
final String USERNAME = "yourUsername";  
final String PASSWORD = "yourPassword";  

// # Go to login page
Connection.Response loginFormResponse = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_FORM_URL)
                                             .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                                             .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                                             .execute();  

// # Fill the login form
// ## Find the form first...
FormElement loginForm = (FormElement)loginFormResponse.parse()
                                         .select("div#login > form").first();
checkElement("Login Form", loginForm);

// ## ... then "type" the username ...
Element loginField = loginForm.select("#login_field").first();
checkElement("Login Field", loginField);
loginField.val(USERNAME);

// ## ... and "type" the password
Element passwordField = loginForm.select("#password").first();
checkElement("Password Field", passwordField);
passwordField.val(PASSWORD);        


// # Now send the form for login
Connection.Response loginActionResponse = loginForm.submit()
         .cookies(loginFormResponse.cookies())
         .userAgent(USER_AGENT)  
         .execute();

System.out.println(loginActionResponse.parse().html());

public static void checkElement(String name, Element elem) {
    if (elem == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find " + name);
    }
}
```

All the form data is handled by the FormElement class for us (even the form method detection). A ready made [Connection](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) is built when invoking the [FormElement#submit](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html#submit--) method. All we have to do is to complete this connection with addional headers (cookies, user-agent etc) and execute it.

Comment: I am trying to do this without the use of the API. I think the main issue is that Google does the Auth in 2 stages, In the normal browser it asks you  to enter the username, then takes you on a 2nd screen to put the password. The example above assumes that both of the Username/Password are present in the first page/auth form.

Comment: @Moe: use the API. "Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide." source: http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/

Comment: My goal is to test this with another custom site that doesn't have an API. I am using goole as an example as I haven't found anything out there to use as a model.

Comment: @Moe I have added a working example (https site==Github) to my post in the **See also** part.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, much appreciated!